# use image tiles as training and validation images and labels in raster vision

Tags: pytorch, rasterio

Can we use image tiles as training and validation images and labels in raster vision? I am working on WMTS xy tiles. i have bunch of satellite images as tiles (training images/labels and validation images/labels). in addition to, i have testing dataset that consists of test images to be used for predictions.

I have tiles. even if i merge them, how to get the geojson as input for label as mentioned in rastervision documentation?